# Vertical jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I would like the following to be achieved:

An image to be clicked on and it will vertically animate a certain amount of pixels (lets say 50) upwards. I want to then click on it again, and it will then animate back down to its original position.

My code so far that doesn't work.

```
$("#content").click(function() {
$("#content").animate(
        {"left": "toggle"},
        "slow");
});
```

Content is just a div in this case. I can do the easy tutorials of clicking a button and it will move the div left or right, but I cannot make the div the button, nor can I make it go up or down.

Help appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="moveMe"><img src="..." /><span>Move Me</span>​</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.moveMe {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.moveMe img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
}

.moveMe span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
}
```

​**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggled = false;
    $('.moveMe').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (toggled){
            $('img', this).stop().animate({top: '0'}, 'slow');
            toggled = false;
        } else {
            $('img', this).stop().animate({top: '-50px'}, 'slow');
            toggled = true;
        }
    });
});​
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y7d9H/1/)

Adjust the CSS `width` and `height` as needed.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var up = false;
    $("#content").click(function() {
       var newTop = "+=50px";
       if (up) {
          newTop = "-=50px";
       }           
       $(this).animate({ top: newTop}, "slow");
       up = !up;
    });
});
```

EDIT: I added `$(document).ready()` above for you. Please also note that the "streaking" that occurs when viewing this animation in jsFiddle is limited to jsFiddle and does not occur regularly on pages.

Good luck! :)

Comment: In case it was unclear, my variable `up` indicated if the element had ALREADY BEEN MOVED UP. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Similar to the response before. Nothing happens.

Comment: If you just added that, then no. Works to a certain degree. Wherever #content is on the screen, it will always jump to the top of the page.

Comment: it shouldn't jump to the top of the page...it should only slide 50px relative to its current position. that's really interesting if it is - can you post a demo of that (or email it to me: contact@zacharykniebel.com)?

Comment: here is a demo of what I gave you (the only thing I changed was the `up` variable to be `goUp` and the if-statement to reflect the change - all just for clarity): http://jsfiddle.net/qFsaF/8/ but I don't see the jumping

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(function(){
 var originalHeight = $("#content").height();
 $("#content").click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $("#content").animate(
      {height: ($this.height()==originalHeight ? (originalHeight+50):originalHeight)},    
      "slow");
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9DSZf/)**

Hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not do anything.

Comment: @JamesMclaren, this evnet must be written in document.ready.  I have updated my answer with the live demo.

Comment: Yes I have added onload. However, it only changed the height. I changed height to top so it moved the div and not change the height. However, similar to the other answers, It will move the div to the top of the page which is not what I want.

Comment: @JamesMclaren, do you need to show some kind of menu that will animate it down and content shown and after clicking on it will become on original position i.e. (hide that content)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ArY36/1/ The div is positioned weird in jsfiddle, on my webpage it is positioned further down the screen.

Comment: @JamesMclaren you haven't added the jquery min. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ArY36/2/